# storage of mipmaps in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

OpenGL version 450 introduces a new function which can be used to allocate memory for a texture2D:

```
glTextureStorage2D(textureObj,levels,internal_format,width,height);
//here, parameter 'levels' refers to the levels of mipmaps
//we need to set it 1 if we only want to use the original texture we loaded because then there is only one mipmap level
```

And, there is a function can help us generate mipmaps for a texture conveniently:

```
glGenerateTextureMipmap(textureObj);
```

So, I have a question: as I need to speciy the size of the storage when I use glTextureStorage2D, do I need to reserve extra space for later using of glGenerateTextureMipmap as mipmap requires extra memory?
I know that I can use glTexImage2D to avoid this problem, that I can first bind the texture to target GL_TEXTURE_2D, then copy the image's data to the texture's memory by using glTexImage2D which only asks me to give the target mipmap level instead of number of mipmap levels, and finally use glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D).

I am a little confused about glGenerateMipmap. Will it allocate extra space for generated mipmap levels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by "reserve extra memory"? You told OpenGL how many mipmaps you wanted when you used `glTextureStorage2D`. When it comes to [immutable storage](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture_Storage#Kinds_of_storage), you don't get to renege. If you say a texture has width W, height H, and mipmap count L, then that's what that texture has. Forever.

As such, `glGenerateTextureMipmaps` will only generate data for the number of mipmaps you put into the texture (minus the base level).

Comment: Is it when I use glTextureStorage2D, as I specify the levels and the size of this texture, OpenGL then allocate memory accroding to the width, the height and the levels?

Comment: And, what does 'minus the base level' mean? Isn't the base level always level 0?
It is, after I call glTextureStorage2D, the function glGenerateTextureMipmaps will only generate mipmaps according to the size of memory allocated by glTextureStorage2D. I thought it was that when I call glGenerateTextureMipmaps, opengl will generate all levels of a texture and spare an extra space to store these mipmaps.

Comment: @SZYoo: "*And, what does 'minus the base level' mean?*" It means `glGenerateTextureMipmaps` will not generate the base mipmap level because... that makes no sense. The base level is a mipmap level, so if it were to "all levels of a texture" would *include* the base level. So it generates the number of mipmaps you put into the texture, except for the base level.

Comment: If I use glTexImage2D, I don't need to tell OpenGL that I want to generate mipmaps for this texture, but I can still call glGenerateMipmap later to generate mipmaps for it. As when mipmaps are generated bigger memory is required, so in this situation, OpenGL can either reserve extra space for this texture's mipmaps when I call glTexImage2D or allocate extra space only when I call  glGenerateMipmap on this texture. Or neither is true. I don't know what happens here. Could you explain it to me? Thank you! :)

Comment: There seems to be some confusion about what it means to "generate mipmaps". Mipmap levels can exist, but they also have particular contents (texels). For immutable storage textures, the number of mipmap levels which exist is determined when the texture's storage is allocated. Calling `glGenerate*Mipmaps` on such a texture will generate texel data for those mipmaps by scaling down the texel data in the base mipmap. For mutable textures, the function will also allocate storage for all of the mipmap levels [specified by the mipmap range](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture#Mipmap_range).

Comment: It seems that I understand. If I use glTextureStorage2D and specify the levels (for example, for size of 1920 * 1080 , set levels = 3) , then OpenGL will allocate enough memory to store 0~3 levels' mipmaps for this texture, and if I use glGenerateTextureMipmaps, OpenGL will only generate 1~3 levels, right? But if I instead use glTexImage2D + glGenerateTextureMipmaps, new storage will be allocated for all levels (0~N, while N is the max level count, from 1920*1080 to 1*1) of the texture. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: So, if I use glTextureStorage2D, I need to calculate the levels the texture needs if I want to let OpenGL generate all levels (from 1920*1080 to 1*1) of mipmaps for it. Like, if there is a texture which's size is 8 * 8, then I need to set the parameter levels 4 and this result is gotten by myself. Is there any function provided by opengl which can help me to get possible count of levels for a texture? As when a texture's size is big, calculating the maximum number of levels of mipmaps that can be generated from it is not easy.